# Problema com JCROP dinâmico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jcrop

Tenho o seguinte código que faz abrir uma modal com o *jcrop* para que faça o recorte e depois colocarei o recorte em um preview, porém quando eu fecho o modal e seleciono outra foto ele não atualiza no modal.

- já mudei pra *class* o código;
- Ele só não muda a foto  do modal quando usa o *Jcrop*;
- Já Usei ->  `$("#blah11").attr("src", " "); E $("#blah11").trigger("reset");`e não resolveu!

segue o código:

```
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    $("#blah11").attr("src", e.target.result);
  };
}
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
$("#modal-ft1").modal("show");
```

Obrigado Desde Já!